Create x.509 certificate using bouncycastle and chain it with ca certificate
I generate a self-signed certificate, then I generate a keystore from that.
I use the generated certificate data to digitally sign a pdf.
The pdf file is created and signed correctly but when I verify the signature using Acrobat Reader it tells me that the validity of the signature is unknown.
I have purchased a valid SSL certificate (including the CA certificate), how do I create the certificate chain to create a valid signature?
This is the part of code for creating the keystore used for sign a pdf

keyStoreFile.createNewFile();

// keys
KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
kpGen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair pair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();

// certificate
X509V3CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
certGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
certGen.setIssuerDN(new X500Principal("CN=xxx"));
certGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000));
certGen.setNotAfter(Date.from(LocalDate.now().plus(365, ChronoUnit.DAYS).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
certGen.setSubjectDN(new X500Principal("CN=xxx"));
certGen.setPublicKey(pair.getPublic());
certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

// extensions
certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false));
certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment));
certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_serverAuth));
certGen.addExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName, false, new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, customer.getEmail())));

X509Certificate cert = certGen.generateX509Certificate(pair.getPrivate(), "BC");

// keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
ks.load(null,null);
ks.setCertificateEntry(customer.getEmail(), cert);
ks.setKeyEntry(" xxx ", pair.getPrivate(), password, new Certificate[]{cert,cert});
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( contractorKeyStorFilePath );
ks.store(fos, password);
fos.close();


There is no way to create a document signing certificate from an SSL certificate. It would break the chain of trust as that would allow anyone to create signing certificates, rendering the whole trust chain worthless. The SSL certificate is a leaf certificate which cannot be used to create other certificates. For that the key usage "certificate signing" should be set for the key pair.
The CA certificate that you've received does contain the certificate signing "key usage" bit set to "true". However, the signing requires possession of the relevant private key, which is not included in the CA certificate; it remains at the CA from which the SSL certificate was retrieved (and that branch of the certificate tree probably only allows TLS authentication certificates). There are ways to create a sub-CA but doing so requires a lot more than just shelving over some money for an SSL certificate (think key protection using HSM's, setting up a certificate policy, certification for IT regulations and audits).
As an end user the only option is to buy a valid (PDF-) singing certificate that can be used for digital signature & non-repudiation as key usage and "document signing" as extended key usage. For signing purposes often these certificates must also contain an email address provided within the certification request.
